# How to get a bootstrap container that is wider than container, but not full width?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a small SPA using angularjs and bootstrap 3 (3.3.7).

The page displays a heading and a single long table with several columns.  My main div class is "container".  When I inspect the content in Firefox, it shows my table is 1170p.

Inside the main div is a header, a checkbox, and a div of class "row" that contains the table.

This was working fine for a while, but I now need to add another column to the table.  As a result, the data in the cells are somewhat squished.  I really need the table to be a little bit wider, but not taking up the full width of the parent container.

I know I can use container-fluid to get the full width, but again, I don't want that.

How can I make it just a little bit wider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom containers if you want, by adding some CSS:

```
.custom-container{
    width: 700px !important;
}
```

If you want them to break like original bootstrap does, you need to add *media queries*:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .custom-container{
    width: 1000px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .custom-container{
    width: 800px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .custom-container{
    width: 650px;
  }
}
```

Afterwards, just add the class to your markup:

```
<div class="container custom-container">
```

Comment: The simple first option works (although I had to set it to 1400) for my situation.  If I want to implement the "break" version later, would I use the same min-width values as you list here, but with my customized values in the width property (for instance, 1400 for the first one)?

Comment: Values I listed are just where I want the width to break. They basically mean that if the device width is greater than or equal to the value in pixels, then do {...}.

Comment: Explaining even deeper, for example, the first query translates to: when the screen width is greater than or equal to 1200px, elements with the custom-container class will be 1000px wide.

Comment: I actually know all that.  I just wanted to know if those are the standard min-width values to check for.

Comment: The standart min-width values are in the bootstrap documentation(for bootstrap 3, in your case): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/, and I think they match the ones I mentioned.